# combine bar graph in python with months, year and records

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

[image]

i want to make such type of graph on python. please guide me. how is it possible.

i have tried `codes` on https://towardsdatascience.com/combo-charts-with-seaborn-and-python-2bc911a08950

Comment: Have you made any attempts? Could you provide a sample of your data?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the graph in an excel spreadsheet where you can copy/paste or download it from excel, you can use openpyxl which is a module allowing you to create and edit excel files. Which means entering data and creating all kinds of charts.